# How do I avoid a StackOverflowException in Hibernate Interceptor auditing

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my Interceptor class

```
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Set<Auditable> inserts = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Auditable> updates = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Auditable> deletes = new HashSet<>();

//  @PrePersist
//  public void doPrePersist(final Auditable entity) {
//      if (entity.isAudited()) {
//          logIt("Create", entity);
//      }
//  }
//  
//  @PreUpdate
//  public void doPreUpdate(final Auditable entity) {
//      if (entity.isAudited()) {
//          logIt("Update", entity);
//      }
//  }
//  
//  @PreRemove
//  public void doPreRemove(final Auditable entity) {
//      if (entity.isAudited()) {
//          logIt("Delete", entity);
//      }
//  }
//  
    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            inserts.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            updates.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
        return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {

        if (entity instanceof Auditable && ((Auditable)entity).isAudited()){
            deletes.add((Auditable)entity);
        }
    }

    //called before commit into database
    @Override
    public void preFlush(Iterator iterator) {
    }

    //called after committed into database
    @Override
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        try {
            for (Auditable entity : inserts) {
                logIt("Saved", entity);
            }

            for (Auditable entity : updates) {
                logIt("Updated", entity); // This is getting called multiple times
            }

            for (Auditable entity : deletes) {
                logIt("Deleted", entity);
            }

        } finally {
            inserts.clear();
            updates.clear();
            deletes.clear();
        }
    }

    public void logIt(String action, Auditable entity) {
        if (!entity.isAudited()) {
            return;
        }
        // I read somewhere that you can't use the same session to write to the db.
        // So I get my ejb session bean (SessionHelper.getSession()).
        // Then I get the injected entitymanager session (.getSession()).
        // Then I get the SessionFactory and open a new session (.getSessionFactory().openSession()).
        Session tempSession = SessionHelper.getSession().getSession().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Audit auditRecord = new Audit(); // This is an entity
        auditRecord.setAction(action);
//      auditRecord.setDetail(entity.toString()); 
        auditRecord.setCreatedTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
        auditRecord.setEntityPK(entity.getPrimaryKeyDisplay()); 
        auditRecord.setEntityName(entity.getClass().toString());
        tempSession.save(auditRecord);
        tempSession.flush(); // this is doing the calling the next postFlush
        // Since this is a different session, I don't see why it should cascade into an infinite loop since the Audit entity is not itself Auditable (.isAuditable() == false).
    }

}
```

All of our EJB entities extend an abstract class `Auditable`, but they may or may not have their .isAuditable() flag set to true. If it is true, it should be added to the appropriate `Set` then logged by an `Audit` entity during the `postFlush`. But the Audit is on a separate Session, and it is a different entity `Audit` that has its `isAuditable` flag set to false, so I am unsure why it is apparently caught in an infinite loop.

The following is the stack trace as requested

```
Exception in thread "Thread-42" javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:137)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:117)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:282)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:330)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:242)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:89)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:319)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:68)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:99)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:270)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:272)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:132)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:260)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:399)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:140)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.updateIssue(Unknown Source)
at com.kable.newsstand.knet.issue.FrmIssue2$SavingThread.doSave(FrmIssue2.java:3810)
at com.kable.newsstand.knet.issue.FrmIssue2$SavingThread.run(FrmIssue2.java:3752)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1223)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:91)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:282)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:330)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:242)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:89)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:319)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:68)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:201)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:57)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.generateConstructor(ReflectionFactory.java:388)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:351)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.lookupNonInitConstructor(SerializableClass.java:556)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.<init>(SerializableClass.java:156)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClassRegistry.lookup(SerializableClassRegistry.java:90)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:165)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:128)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.cloneFields(SerializingCloner.java:393)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:301)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:251)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:128)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.cloneFields(SerializingCloner.java:393)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:301)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.initSerializableClone(SerializingCloner.java:276)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:251)
at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:128)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:313)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:304)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:271)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:184)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:58)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocation(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:42)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:125)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy317.getSession(Unknown Source)
at com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.audit.AuditInterceptor.logIt(AuditInterceptor.java:107)
at com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.audit.AuditInterceptor.postFlush(AuditInterceptor.java:89)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postPostFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:401)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:66)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
```

This last part just keeps repeating

```
at com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.audit.AuditInterceptor.logIt(AuditInterceptor.java:115)
at com.kable.newsstand.kdsejb.audit.AuditInterceptor.postFlush(AuditInterceptor.java:89)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postPostFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:401)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:66)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Daniele Edited for stack trace. I couldn't post it all because of limited post space, but that last part just keeps repeating.

Comment: Uhm in the logIt() call you are saving again using hibernate, and the operation is audited and logged again, and so on.. is that right? do you have any mechanism in place to break the loop?

Comment: No, In the `logIt()` method, I am creating a different entity of class `Audit` (`Audit` is a subclass of `Auditable` but it has its `isAudited()` flag sett to false so it shouldn't trigger .

Answer (score 1):

So the solution I came up with is to remove the entity from the collection before I logIt().

```
public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
    try {
        for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = inserts.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
//          for (Auditable entity : inserts) {
            Auditable entity = iter.next();
            iter.remove();
            logIt("Saved", entity);
        }

        for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = updates.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
//          for (Auditable entity : updates) {
            Auditable entity = iter.next();
            iter.remove();
            logIt("Updated", entity);
        }

        for (Iterator<Auditable> iter = deletes.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
//          for (Auditable entity : deletes) {
            Auditable entity = iter.next();
            iter.remove();
            logIt("Deleted", entity);
        }

    } finally {
        inserts.clear();
        updates.clear();
        deletes.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me but I have a  question, if we use inserts, updates Set which are declared as instance variable, will it work properly for concurrent requests?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your assumptions are wrong and you need to check them in order.

First you need to check that you really get *new* session. If you get the same session you are in trouble as `onFlush` called from `logIt` will start to iterate over the same collection of entities to be audited.

Another possible reason is that `Audit.isAudited` returns `true`. You need to check this as well.